# select inside insert statmen and procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, select, stored-procedures, insert

can i want to create store procedure that get arguments and run an select statment inside the insert statment?

i got 2 question:
1)how to get arguments on store procedure?
2)can i run select statment in insert statment like this?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `insertGuide` @m_name varchar(45)  ,@m_last varchar(45) ,@addres varchar(45) ,@mphone int

BEGIN
INSERT INTO `guides` (`id`, `name`, `lastName`, `address`, `phone`)
 VALUES (select max(id)+1 from seq,@m_name,@m_last,@addres,@mphone);

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the first question, but regarding the **INSERT** statement, this should work

```
INSERT INTO `guides` (`id`, `name`, `lastName`, `address`, `phone`)
select max(id)+1, @m_name, @m_last, @addres, @mphone
from seq;
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insertGuide;

CREATE PROCEDURE insertGuide (id int, name varchar(45)  ,last varchar(45) ,addres    varchar(45) ,phone int(12)) 

BEGIN
INSERT INTO `guides` (`id`, `name`, `lastName`, `address`, `phone`)
VALUES (id, name, last, addres, phone);
END
```

you can run select query in insert like:

```
INSERT INTO `guides` (`id`, `name`, `lastName`, `address`, `phone`)
SELECT MAX(id)+1, @m_name, @m_last, @addres, @mphone
FROM seq;
```